# Did anyone used MUNIT for API integeration testing?

Tags: test-automation-framework, api-testing

Did anyone use MUNIT for API integration testing?
I'm exploring options to build automation suite for API's and among different options, there is not enough information regarding munit.

Could someone point out the pros/cons of using munit?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1/

Comment: Why not to use SoapUI or Jmeter? Both are great API testing tools and have a big online community & support.

Comment: Using postman at the moment, wanted to reuse api methods for UI automation. that is the reason behind going for API Automation framework